# What are the differences between setting DOM attribute directly and via requestAnimationFrame?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am reading BluePrintJS source code and noticed they put DOM element attributes changing logic inside a `requestAnimationFrame` block. What are the differences to set DOM attribute directly and via requestAnimationFrame?

```
private handlePopoverClosing = (node: HTMLElement) => {
    // restore focus to saved element.
    // timeout allows popover to begin closing and remove focus handlers beforehand.
    requestAnimationFrame(() => {
        if (this.previousFocusedElement !== undefined) {
            this.previousFocusedElement.focus();
            this.previousFocusedElement = undefined;
        }
    });

    const { popoverProps = {} } = this.props;
    Utils.safeInvoke(popoverProps.onClosing, node);
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Performance. `requestAnimationFrame` will be run when at the start of a render frame, which helps with something known as [layout thrashing](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/performance/rendering/avoid-large-complex-layouts-and-layout-thrashing).

By doing this you group all DOM changes into one frame which is done all at once rather than spreading rendering logic across multiple frames, which is more expensive (DOM work is s l o w).

The general idea is that you want to group DOM writes such that they happen before DOM reads instead of interspersing reads among writes - rAF does that by ensuring the write happens at a specific time, with other writes.